# Embed web page into another website (Custom scrollbar)

Tags: iframe, scrollbar, embed, tinyscrollbar

This might be a bit odd to explain but here goes:

I am trying to embed a tumblr blog into a website so they can update their own schedule and they want to use the actual page itself. Initially we used an iframe which was fine however the catch is we are using a custom scrollbar (http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/).

The iframe pops up its own regular scrollbar that scrolls the embedded website. The custom scrollbar just moves the iframe itself up and down a bit and not the content inside. (The same seemed to go for an object/embed tag as well)

Is there a better way that will work with what we want to do or is there some scripting I am not aware of to make all of this work? The webpage in question is here - http://www.brettloudermilk.com/temp/schedule.html

I'd post some of the code but not sure what would help here exactly...

Answer (score 0):

Are the iframes page and website on the same domain? If so you can get the iframes document get its current height and set the iframe's height accordantly. After that you will need to update the scrollbar.

```
var $scroller = $( "#youscrollbarid" ).tinyscrollbar();

$('#youriframesid').load(function() {
    this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
    $scroller.tinyscrollbar_update();
});
```

Comment: The content will change as it's added to so I can't set the iframe height to that of the content. I did try to hide the iframe scrollbar and nothing moved.

Comment: They are on two separate servers so unfortunately no. I might just have to face facts this might not be possible.